# System.ArgumentException : Duplicate dynamic module name within an assembly in Nhibernate 3.3.0.4000

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nuget

I'm having an issue I cannot reproduce and I cannot track down.  It happens for one client, in one area of the site, on one environment only.

> System.ArgumentException : Duplicate dynamic module name within an assembly.

**StackTrace**

```
at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderData.CheckNameConflict(String strNewModuleName) at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModuleInternalNoLock(String name, Boolean emitSymbolInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at 
System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModuleInternal(String name, Boolean emitSymbolInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at 
System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(String name) at 
NHibernate.Proxy.DynamicProxy.DefaultProxyAssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(String moduleName) at NHibernate.Proxy.DynamicProxy.ProxyFactory.CreateUncachedProxyType(Type baseType, Type[] baseInterfaces) at 
NHibernate.Proxy.DynamicProxy.ProxyFactory.CreateProxyType(Type baseType, Type[] interfaces) at NHibernate.Proxy.DynamicProxy.ProxyFactory.CreateProxy(Type instanceType, IInterceptor interceptor, Type[] baseInterfaces) at 
NHibernate.Proxy.DefaultProxyFactory.GetProxy(Object id, ISessionImplementor session)
```

There are numerous posts saying that it's a problem with `Castle.DynamicProxy` but the version of nhibernate I am using does not need/use the castle library.  I am using NuGet for my `FluentNHibernate` reference and everything is up to date.

I checked the bin on the server and there is no castle dll.  The nhibernate dll is the correct version.

Comment: Pls add all your configuration code, maybe you set dynamic proxy when you don't need to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a race condition bug in NHibernate, see https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3172.

It is fixed in 3.3.1GA which should be available for download within a few hours.

Comment: You were absolutely correct.  After your reply I was able to get an update from Nuget and the problem seems to have resolved itself.  I just needed some patience.  Thank you!

Comment: FYI I've just gotten this in v3.3.3.4000. https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3172?focusedCommentId=29163&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-29163

Comment: @roydukkey Sounds odd - it will be interesting to see the stacktrace when you attach it to the issue.